# How use typescript for formData object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How add type for formData object?
How to specify the type for the **formData** object before sending it to the server (in order to recognize this object not as a simple form date, but as a formDate limited by the interface)

**Example:**

```
export interface IContactForm {
  company?: string
  firstName: string
}

 const onFormSubmit = async (contactFormData: IContactForm) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    for (const field in contactFormData) {
      formData.append(field, contactFormData[field])
    }
    
    sendData(formData) // how specify formData type here?
}

const sendData = (data: ? I don't want just specify it as formData but with interface) {

}
```